# App crash when try to define rightBarButtonItems

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using this methods to define navigationItem rightBarButtonItems:

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YouTube-icon"]];
UIBarButtonItem *barIcon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:imageView];

if ([videoArr count] > 0) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barIcon,self.aToZButton, nil];
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barIcon;
}

[imageView release];
[barIcon release];
```

And when the debug is on :

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barIcon,self.aToZButton, nil];
```

The app crash with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5eecd0'
```

## Edit

I noticed that the crash happen only when i am using rightBarButtonItem and then rightBarButtonItem.
If i use only rightBarButtonItems it's won't crash

Comment: Why are you releasing imageView twice?

Comment: It's mistake , i edit the code

Comment: Show ur code for aToZButton as well

Comment: I create this button in the inteface builder, and connect it with iboutlet

Comment: are you sure self.aToZButton is UIBarButtonItem ???

Comment: Yep, i noticed that the crash happen when i first set rightBarButtonItem an then the rightBarButtonItems, but if i set onlt the rightBarButtonItems it's work.any idea?

Comment: Does it crash if you set just the `rightBarButtonItem` or does it have to be item then items to see the crash?

Comment: have to be item then items and it crash

Comment: ok. remove last two release lines and see if app is still crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like somewhere down the line you're releasing the object too early(memory management issue).`NSCFType` is an internal undocumented class in the iOS SDK, the fact behind it showed up here means the memory space of your class got freed before the process get completed.